# Modifier in @Compose functions in Android Studio Kotlin Programming Language

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, modifier, viewmodifier

What is difference between modifier (small m) and Modifier (capital M) when it is used in the @Compose Functions in Android Studio?

I am receiving the following output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkO8X.png)
by using the following code

```
`@Composable
fun ComposeQuadrant(){
    Column (
        Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ){
        Row (Modifier.weight(1f)){
            DisplayTheText(
                name = stringResource(R.string.text_composable),
                define = stringResource(R.string.text_composable_define),
                color = colorResource(R.color.color_1),
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
            DisplayTheText(
                name = stringResource(R.string.image_composable),
                define = stringResource(R.string.image_composable_define),
                color = colorResource(R.color.color_2),
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
        }
        Row (Modifier.weight(1f)){
            DisplayTheText(
                name = stringResource(R.string.row_composable),
                define = stringResource(R.string.row_composable_define),
                color = colorResource(R.color.color_3),
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
            DisplayTheText(
                name = stringResource(R.string.column_composable),
                define = stringResource(R.string.column_composable_define),
                color = colorResource(R.color.color_4),
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DisplayTheText(name : String, define :String, color : Color, modifier: Modifier =Modifier){
    Column (
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
**        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color)
            .padding(16.dp)**
    ){
        Text(
            text = name,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = 16.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = define,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Justify,
        )
    }
}`
```

If I use the modifier with Capital M inplace of Bold part in above code i am not getting the desired result.

```
    Column (
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
**        modifier = modifier**
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color)
            .padding(16.dp)
```

i was trying the following

```
    **modifier = Modifier**
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(color)
        .padding(16.dp)
```

Where as i got my result with

```
    **modifier = modifier**
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(color)
        .padding(16.dp)
```

Answer (score 0):

- **short answer:**

basically in your case **modifier(small m)** is the name of the parameter you are passing to your composable `DisplayTheText` and **Modifier(capital M)** is the actual compose `modifier`.

- **long answer**

in compose its recommended to pass a `modifier` to each composable so that you can pass to it a different modifier for each case (fill all width / fill half / blue background...)
so to pass that `modifier` to it we pass it as a paramater :

```
@Composable
fun DisplayTheText(name : String, define :String, color : Color, modifier: Modifier =Modifier){
    Column (
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = modifier
    ){
     //code
    }
}
```

and then when we call it we give it the disired `modifier` we want or if we don't pass the `modifier` parameter it will take the default/empty `modifier`.

note that if make our `modifier` like this:

```
@Composable
fun DisplayTheText(name : String, define :String, color : Color, modifier: Modifier =Modifier){
    Column (
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = modifier.padding(8.dp)
                     .clickable{//code}
    ){
     //code
    }
}
```

then we call our composable like this:

```
DisplayTheText(
            name = stringResource(R.string.row_composable),
            define = stringResource(R.string.row_composable_define),
            color = colorResource(R.color.color_3),
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        )
```

what will happen is the `modifier` will actually take the `weight modifier` first then take the the rest `modifiers` that we passed as fixed `modifier` so it will be like this:

```
Modifier
   .weight(1f)
   .padding(8.dp)
   .clickable{//code}
```

**small tip: the order of modifiers matter significantly [read this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers#order-modifier-matters) to understand**